# Why gravitational lensing appears circular?

Tags: black-holes, geometry, dark-matter, gravitational-lensing

I still remember the black hole photo but I know the coffee mug stain is actually the materials orbiting around it appears to be getting pervertedly blended 720 degree around the sphere, but then what about the dark matter presence in each galaxy are they spherical too then how to explain some light paths from a single source taking much longer like up to a year to reach us in the form of Einstein's cross?

Comment: Which black hole photo?

Comment: @shaihorowitz: galaxy m87 taken in 2019

Answer (score -1):

Space and time are ENTANGLED, it is because of the masses of the bodies - stars, galaxies, black holes, etc., -
that there is curvature of space-time, that is, the combined FOUR-DIMENSIONS of our universe.
The effect of bending of light by passing through the space around a massive body caused by the curvature of space-time around it, is in fact, gravitational lensing.
As a matter of fact, gravitational lensing applies to all of the electromagnetic spectrum as the space-time curvature can bend any spectra. This property also enables us to view the far distant bright bodies, like quasars, galaxies, supernovae, etc., that are behind massive bodies that pave the way for them to be detected.
Modern researchers are also using and experimenting this method of research to explore hidden secrets of dark matter and energy linked to the far stretched unknown realm of it.